# Magento 2.3 Data Transfer Import

Tags: magento2.3

I want to upload my products via .csv files but in my Magento Backend there is no option to import the file. Normally it should be under System-Data Transfer-Import but there is no option like Import or Export. Its just empty under Transfer Import.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your admin user has full access or limited access ?

Comment: It has full access

Comment: are you using custom theme ? make sure also your admin has full access in role resources